# SQL SERVER example with checkbox

Tags: sql, sql-server, checkbox

Need your help with checkboxes.
Here is my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE stad_list

@inp_location_code numeric (3,0) = -1
@inp_item_code_bgn numeric (5,0) = -1
@inp_item_code_end numeric (5,0) = -1
@inp_shipped numeric (2,0) = 0,    --checkbox, if it is checked then returns the items in table which were shipped (value in table is 1)
@inp_check numeric (2,0) = 0, --checkbox, if it is checked then returns data which is still in process of checking for availability in warehouse (value in table is 0)
@inp_not_ship numeric(2,0) = 0   --checkbox, if it is checked then returns data which had not been shipped during some problems (valuein table is 2)

AS

BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   DECLARE @SELECT as varchar (3000) = ''
   DECLARE @WHERE as varchar (1000) = ''

   IF (@inp_location_code != -1)
      SET @WHERE = @WHERE + ' WHERE [dbo].item.location =' + CONVERT(varchar,@inp_location_code)

   IF (@inp_item_code_bgn != -1)
       SET @WHERE = @WHERE + ' AND [dbo].item.code>=' + CONVERT(varchar, @inp_item_code_bgn)

   IF (@inp_item_code_end != -1)
       SET @WHERE = @WHERE + ' AND [dbo].item.code<=' + CONVERT(varchar, @inp_item_code_end)

   IF (@inp_shipped = 1)
      SET @WHERE = @WHERE + ' AND [dbo].item.ship = 1'

   IF (@inp_check = 1)
      SET @WHERE = @WHERE + ' AND [dbo].item.ship = 0'

   IF (@inp_not_ship = 1)
      SET @WHERE = @WHERE + ' AND [dbo].item.ship = 2'



    SET @SELECT = @SELECT + '
        SELECT
             [dbo].item.name as ''NAME'',
             [dbo].item.location as ''LOCATION'',
             [dbo].item.code as ''CODE'',
             [dbo].item.ship as ''STATUS''
        FROM [dbo].item '
        + @WHERE 


    EXEC (@SELECT)

    RETURN @@ROWCOUNT

END
```

It works fine when i am checking only one check box, but cant get any data while 2 of it are checked. So what to do in case when i want to check two check boxes? Any suggestions?

here is my table

```
Id     Item_code    Item_name   Item_location   Item_ship
1      14789        Juice       Tokyo            0
2      14785        Boots       Tokyo            2
3      98744        Hat         Osaka            0
4      36987        Socks       Kyoto            1
```

And there is three checkboxes

- Shipped
- Checking
- Not shipped

If i check shipped then output will be like this:

```
Id     Item_code    Item_name   Item_location   Item_ship
    4      36987        Socks       Kyoto            1
```

but i want to do so for ex. when i check Shipped and Checking then the output will be:

```
Id     Item_code    Item_name   Item_location   Item_ship
    1      14789        Juice       Tokyo            0
    3      98744        Hat         Osaka            0
    4      36987        Socks       Kyoto            1
```

Comment: not enough info. need sample input data and expected output.

Comment: Replace ANDs with ORs for checkboxes part. Do not forget parenthesises around ORed conditions.

Comment: I have edited my question with examples as you asked...sorry if it is too long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use temp table as table of parameters

```
IF (@inp_shipped = 1) OR (@inp_check = 1) OR (@inp_not_ship = 1)
BEGIN
  IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Parameters') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.#Parameters
  SELECT *
  INTO #Parameters
  FROM (
        SELECT CASE WHEN @inp_shipped = 1 THEN 1 END AS Ship
        UNION ALL
        SELECT CASE WHEN @inp_check = 1 THEN 0 END
        UNION ALL
        SELECT CASE WHEN @inp_not_ship = 1 THEN 2 END
        ) p
   WHERE p.Ship IS NOT NULL     
   SET @WHERE = @WHERE + ' AND [dbo].item.ship IN (SELECT ship FROM #Parameters)'
 END
```

For better performance(made ​​to use index seek operation) if you have an index on the ship column, need to create an index on a temporary table:

```
CREATE INDEX x ON #Parameters(ship)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer it is works) but can you explain what is the 'p' and how OBJECT_ID is used in this case? thank you in advance!

Comment: No problem.SELECT..INTO creates a new table(in my answer creates temp table #Parameters) and inserts the resulting rows from the query into it, but before inserting I check existed table or not.

Answer (score 1):

You could combine you options into this kind of construction:

```
declare @orcheck varchar(255)
set @orcheck = 'AND 1=2 ('

IF (@inp_shipped = 1)
SET @orcheck = @orcheck + ' OR [dbo].item.ship = 1'

IF (@inp_check = 1)
SET @orcheck = @orcheck + ' OR [dbo].item.ship = 0'

IF (@inp_not_ship = 1)
SET @orcheck = @orcheck + ' OR [dbo].item.ship = 2'

set @orcheck = @orcheck + ')'
```

This way, when you have all 3 checkboxes selected, the WHERE clause would look like this:

```
AND (1=2
    OR [dbo].item.ship = 1
    OR [dbo].item.ship = 0
    OR [dbo].item.ship = 2
)
```

And when nothing is select, it would be:

```
AND (1=2
)
```

Which is what you expect, I believe.

Comment: Thank you for your answer too! it is also useful! really appreciate your answer)